# How to remap key combinations in Karabiner Elements?

Tags: macos, key, karabiner

i have currently switched to mac. However I am used to the keybinds in Windows.
I want to map the keybinds differently so they resemble the windows keys.

Especially i want to change following keys:

Option + 5 = [ (in mac) to: control + command + 7 = [ (like in Windows)

etc.

How do I do that in Karabiner Elements?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right (= you want to press Ctrl-Cmd-7 on a Mac keyboard) this will do:

```
{  "description": "Option-5 to Option-Cmd-7",
   "manipulators": [ {
             "type": "basic",
             "from": { "key_code": "7",
                         "modifiers": {
                           "mandatory": [ "left_control", "left_command" ]
                     }                },
               "to": [
                     { "key_code": "5",
                         "modifiers": "left_option",
                       "repeat": false  }
                     ]
                   } ]
}
```

This rule/re-map will produce a "[" bracket in any writing app.
You can insert it into your Karabiner.json file manually or import it as Complex Modification.

Comment: Where do I put this JSON though?

Comment: Your karabiner.json file is at . . . /Users/[your name]/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json . . . while a "complex_modification" can be put into sub folder "assets/complex_modifications" . . . Have a peaceful day & stay healthy.